# Disable eslint parsing error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

In my code I have a conditional export:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing')
  export myFunc;
```

In es6 this statement is not allowed because imports and exports should be top-level, but using babel with some plugins and webpack this condition is eliminated at build-time, so in my resulting code this export is either top-level or not present.

But eslint reports a parsing error and I want to get rid of it. `/*eslint-disable */` doesn't work, because, well, it's not a rule violation, it's a parsing error. Is there a possible workaround?

P.S.: I know I can commonjs it, but I want to stick with es6.

Comment: Is your eslint configured to parse es6? http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-language-options

Comment: @RadosławM, sure, that's why it reports about wrong es6 syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround.

> Using non-top level imports will not work with native ES6 implementations. Babel allows it because it transpiles to CommonJS require, but it is technically not allowed in ES6.

[eslint issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2259) and according [espree issue](https://github.com/eslint/espree/issues/124)

Comment: I don't rely on transpiling to commonjs to have conditional export, I use it as a preprocessor directive.

Comment: Yes, but eslint parser (espree) see the not transpiled code - `if (...) {import ...}`

Comment: I agree. That's why I want to find a way to make him pretend he doesn't see it the same way I can ask him to pretend that he doesn't see a rule violation.

Comment: But it's eslint issue, but espree. You can't ignore espree errors and warnings through *eslint-disable* rules.

Comment: But it's **not** eslint issue, but espree. *

Answer (score 2):

> I know I can commonjs it, but I want to stick with es6.

Really, you aren't compliant with ES6 specification, so... you need to *commonjs it*.

The Idea behind a *transpiler* is that you'll can disable it when the next specification comes actual.

In this case, your code won't work in a full ES6 environment.